# angular api datatable : no data found

Tags: json, angular, api

I'm trying to make a table with this API:
https://run.mocky.io/v3/70e5b0ad-7112-41c5-853e-b382a39e65b7/people
the html structure of my table appears but not the data of my API and I have no error in the console

Do you have a solution ?

here is the structure of my rest component (code of my table):

people.ts

```
export class people {
    id: string; 
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    email: string;
    mobile: string; 
    city: string;
    country: string;

    constructor(id,firstName,lastName,email,mobile,city,country){
        this.id=id;
        this.firstname=firstName;
        this.lastname=lastName;
        this.email=email;
        this.mobile=mobile;
        this.city=city;
        this.country=country;
    }
}
```

rest.component.html

```
  <h1>Employee Dashboard</h1>
    
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>City</th>
          <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor= "let user of users">
          <td>{{people.id}}</td>
          <td>{{people.firstname}}</td>
          <td>{{people.lastname}}</td>
          <td>{{people.email}}</td>
          <td>{{people.address}}</td>
          <td>{{people.city}}</td>
          <td>{{people.country}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

rest.component.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './rest.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(`should have as title 'project'`, () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('project');
  });

  it('should render title in a h1 tag', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toContain('Welcome to project!');
  });
});
```

rest.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { people } from './people';
import { RestService } from './rest.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './rest.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rest.component.css']
})
export class RestComponent implements OnInit {
  people: people[] = [];
  constructor(public rs: RestService){

  }
  ngOnInit():void {
    this.rs.getUsers().subscribe((response) => {
this.people=response;
    })
  }
  title = 'project';
}
```

rest.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { people } from './people'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RestService {
 constructor(private http:HttpClient){}

 url:string= "https://run.mocky.io/v3/70e5b0ad-7112-41c5-853e-b382a39e65b7/people";
 getUsers(){
   return this.http.get<people[]>(this.url);
 }

}
```

Comment: Hey, First thing You missed `<tr *ngFor= "let user of users"> <td>{{people.id}}</td>` there should be user.id

Comment: it still doesn't work even with user instead of people but ty ;)

Answer (score 1):

The actual array of People objects is under a property named "people" in the API response. So, modify the service code:

```
getUsers(){
   return this.http.get<any>(this.url).pipe(
   map(response) => {
      return response['people'];
   })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you will need to change will be in two files

1. rest.component.html

   Replace this

   ```
   <tr *ngFor= "let user of users">
     <td>{{people.id}}</td>
     <td>{{people.firstname}}</td>
     <td>{{people.lastname}}</td>
     <td>{{people.email}}</td>
     <td>{{people.address}}</td>
     <td>{{people.city}}</td>
     <td>{{people.country}}</td>
   </tr>
   ```

   with this

   ```
   <tr *ngFor= "let user of users">
     <td>{{user.id}}</td>
     <td>{{user.firstname}}</td>
     <td>{{user.lastname}}</td>
     <td>{{user.email}}</td>
     <td>{{user.address}}</td>
     <td>{{user.city}}</td>
     <td>{{user.country}}</td>
   </tr>
   ```
2. In rest.component.ts

   Replace

   ```
   ngOnInit():void {
       this.rs.getUsers().subscribe((response) => {
   this.people=response;
       })
   ```

   with this

   ```
   ngOnInit():void {
       this.rs.getUsers().subscribe((response) => {
   this.users=response.people;
       })
   ```

Comment: i have " Property 'people' does not exist on type 'people[]' " and Property 'users' does not exist on type 'RestComponent'

Answer (score -1):

It should be user.id not people.id

```
        <tr *ngFor= "let user of users">
          <td>{{user.id}}</td>
          <td>{{user.firstname}}</td>
          <td>{{user.lastname}}</td>
          <td>{{user.email}}</td>
          <td>{{user.address}}</td>
          <td>{{user.city}}</td>
          <td>{{user.country}}</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: it still doesn't work even with user instead of people but ty ;)

Comment: @KalSttr either change this variable name people: people[] = []; to users: people[] = [];   or change in html <tr *ngFor= "let p of people">
          <td>{{p.id}}</td>
          <td>{{p.firstname}}</td>
          <td>{{p.lastname}}</td>
          <td>{{p.email}}</td>
          <td>{{p.address}}</td>
          <td>{{p.city}}</td>
          <td>{{p.country}}</td>
        </tr>

Comment: @KalSttr you are using it as let user of users in html but in ts file the variable name is not users it is people. make it same at both place. either change its name in ts file as users: people[] = []; or in html file as let p of people because variable name is people in ts file.

Comment: i tried both solution, it doesn't work ;)

Answer (score -1):

The problem with code is you saving data in people and in frontend you are using `user` which is not defined.

```
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor= "let p of people">
          <td>{{p.id}}</td>
          <td>{{p.firstname}}</td>
          <td>{{p.lastname}}</td>
          <td>{{p.email}}</td>
          <td>{{p.address}}</td>
          <td>{{p.city}}</td>
          <td>{{p.country}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```